# how to send text file to HC 05 bluetooth from android application

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, 8051

My HC 05 Bluetooth module is connected with 8051 at receive side.
I want to send **simple text file** using android mobile to HC 05 module.
How could i do that?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I can send single byte to HC 05. so communication is proper.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java.

First of all, you should get default Bluetooth adapter:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Next you should get MAC address of your HC-05, you can just check it in connection list in Bluetooth settings of your phone, or you can scan nearby devices in your app and check their names:

```
/* Check HC-05 in paired devices */
public void findInPairedDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                MACaddress = device.getAddress();
            }
        }
    }
}
/* Scan nearby devices for HC-05 */
public void findInAvailableDevices() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                    MACaddress = device.getAddress();
                    adapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    activity.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    /* Permission for Bluetooth search */
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    adapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

After getting MAC address you can get your HC-05:

```
BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(MACaddress);
```

And can create socket:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
```

Where `myUUID` is your UUID which you can get using:

```
myUUID = UUID.fromString("Your UUID string");
```

Finally, start socket:

```
socket.connect();
```

Next you can use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` for communicating with HC-05:

```
if (socket.isConnected()) { 
       InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
       OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
}
```

For reading input message:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
int bytes;
bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
String inMsg = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

And for writing output message:

```
String outStr = "Meow";
outputStream.write(outStr.getBytes());
```

After work you should close streams and socket:

```
inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
socket.close();
```

Note: you mustn't forget about exceptions.